# Latex does not work in Python's matplotlib

Tags: pdftex, miktex, python, matplotlib

I installed MikTex and try to plot some graphs using Matplotlib. There, I want to use Latex, but I get the following error:

```
 File "C:\Users\Leo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\texmanager.py", line 277, in _run_checked_subprocess
   stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)

 File "C:\Users\Leo\anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 411, in check_output
   **kwargs).stdout

 File "C:\Users\Leo\anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 512, in run
   output=stdout, stderr=stderr)

CalledProcessError: Command '['latex', '-interaction=nonstopmode', '--halt-on-error', 'C:\\Users\\Leo\\.matplotlib\\tex.cache\\d97ff769cca1b07656427b11e7187cec.tex']' returned non-zero exit status 1.


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):

 File "C:\Users\Leo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\formatters.py", line 341, in __call__
   return printer(obj)

 File "C:\Users\Leo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\pylabtools.py", line 248, in <lambda>
   png_formatter.for_type(Figure, lambda fig: print_figure(fig, 'png', **kwargs))

 File "C:\Users\Leo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\pylabtools.py", line 132, in print_figure
   fig.canvas.print_figure(bytes_io, **kw)

 File "C:\Users\Leo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backend_bases.py", line 2193, in print_figure
   self.figure.draw(renderer)

 File "C:\Users\Leo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line 41, in draw_wrapper
   return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)

 File "C:\Users\Leo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\figure.py", line 1864, in draw
   renderer, self, artists, self.suppressComposite)

 File "C:\Users\Leo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\image.py", line 131, in _draw_list_compositing_images
   a.draw(renderer)

 File "C:\Users\Leo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line 41, in draw_wrapper
   return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)

 File "C:\Users\Leo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\cbook\deprecation.py", line 411, in wrapper
   return func(*inner_args, **inner_kwargs)

 File "C:\Users\Leo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py", line 2747, in draw
   mimage._draw_list_compositing_images(renderer, self, artists)

 File "C:\Users\Leo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\image.py", line 131, in _draw_list_compositing_images
   a.draw(renderer)

 File "C:\Users\Leo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line 41, in draw_wrapper
   return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)

 File "C:\Users\Leo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axis.py", line 1166, in draw
   renderer)

 File "C:\Users\Leo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axis.py", line 1092, in _get_tick_bboxes
   for tick in ticks if tick.label1.get_visible()],

 File "C:\Users\Leo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axis.py", line 1092, in <listcomp>
   for tick in ticks if tick.label1.get_visible()],

 File "C:\Users\Leo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\text.py", line 900, in get_window_extent
   bbox, info, descent = self._get_layout(self._renderer)

 File "C:\Users\Leo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\text.py", line 287, in _get_layout
   ismath="TeX" if self.get_usetex() else False)

 File "C:\Users\Leo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_agg.py", line 228, in get_text_width_height_descent
   s, fontsize, renderer=self)

 File "C:\Users\Leo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\texmanager.py", line 423, in get_text_width_height_descent
   dvifile = self.make_dvi(tex, fontsize)

 File "C:\Users\Leo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\texmanager.py", line 311, in make_dvi
   texfile], tex)

 File "C:\Users\Leo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\texmanager.py", line 290, in _run_checked_subprocess
   exc=exc.output.decode('utf-8'))) from exc

RuntimeError: latex was not able to process the following string:
b'lp'

Here is the full report generated by latex:
failed to create process.
```

I have installed TexLive and can call it from the commmand prompt by typing latex. It is located in the folder `C:\texlive`

I have previously installed MikTex and been trying to solve this for hours now, please help me!

Comment: I suggest you have a look at export to TikZ instead: https://pypi.org/project/matplotlib2tikz/

Comment: Hm, that does not work either. I now get the error: LaTeX returned an error, probably missing font or error in preamble.

Comment: Could you add the Python code that triggered this error to your question? That might be helpful as it allows to check if the problem is in the input or in the installation.

Comment: Provide a minimal matplotlib example that you're using which generates this. cf https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41453109/how-to-write-your-own-latex-preamble-in-matplotlib#comment130799597_41453758